# Verifying all Keys in an Array

Tags: php

Currently, this is what I do to check if all keys of an array **$A** are **within a subset** of another array **$B**.

```
$B = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

if(array_keys($A) == array_intersect(array_keys($A), $B))
{
 action if true
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more straight forward way of doing this, something like the `in_array()` function.

**Usage Example**:

Checking the $_POST array to ensure that all keys matches a dynamic form and filter out extra keys if the form is hacked.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: @ Gordon, means I have to create keys for array B

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: means you might have to clarify the question if its not what you are looking for ;)

Comment: such referenes are somewhat against SO rules. or, at least, habits.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: unless you point me to that rule or a meta post, there is no such rule at SO. Im doing those ever since I joined SO and no one ever complained about it. On the contrary I might add.

Comment: @ Gordon, if array $A has more keys than array $B, would it be a true or a false?

Comment: @Ben it wouldnt be true nor false because `array_intersect_key` *returns an associative array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all arguments.* A possible alternative would be `array_diff_key`. But like I said, you might want to clarify what you are trying to do; especially on the subset part. Maybe give some examples.

Comment: @ Gordon, I am referring to array-key-exists function.

Comment: @Ben `array_key_exists` checks for one key at a time only.

Comment: @ Gordon, usage example above. I see, array_key_exist doesn't work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (array_diff_key($A, array_flip($B))) {
    // there are keys in $A that are *not* in $B!
}
```

or possibly:

```
if (array_diff_key(array_flip($B), $A)) {
    // not all of the keys in $B are in $A!
}
```

Comment: I highlighted with a subset, in case you didn't see.

Comment: It's actually kind of confusing what you want. Do you want to confirm that all `$B` keys are in your array `$A`?

Comment: likely any variation of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array_diff_key+user%3A476

Comment: @ deceze: I want to confirm that all keys in array $A is with array $B. Your difference method does not test for such condition.

Comment: @Ben It very well does it. `array_diff_key` "returns all keys from [the first argument] that are not in [the second argument]". If the return is empty/`false`, that means all keys of the first argument are in the second.

Comment: @ deceze: It's hard to see, but I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Not perhaps that straight forward to read, but [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php#38129) in the PHP manual for [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) provides a compact way of checking whether an array is a subset of another.

```
if (array_unique(array_keys($a) + $b) == $b)
{
    echo 'valid array keys';
}
```

[Test example](http://codepad.org/aKgyktpk)

Comment: But considering the number of operations performed, I think I will take deceze method. Thanks for your answer ;D

Comment: @Ben: Yup, and as a bonus you get the extra array keys and values straight away in deceze's method: `if ($extra_values = array_diff_key(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

No, your way is probably the same way I would have used. If you need to compare against a list, an array is the best solution. Though I would have probably used `array_intersect_keys_` instead.

Comment: Seems like there are more than one way to do this.